# Bind query parameters to complex type with class[field] syntax

Tags: .net-core, query-string

We are trying to upgrade an old system and maintain backwards compatibility. The old .net framework 4.7.2, MVC system had an API endpoint which could accept parameters in the format of class[field], for example:

```
https://localhost:44301/api/AddClass?schoolClass[name]=Math&schoolClass[level]=1&instructor[name]=bob
```

for the controller endpoint:

```
public Response Get(HttpRequestMessage hrequest, [FromUri]SchoolClass schoolClass, [FromUri]Instructor instructor)
```

Looking at the model binding in net core 6.0, it looks like it only accepts it in the format of class.field.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

While the bracket parameters are reserved for parameters which are collections.

Is there a way to bind class[field] to a parameter from the query string in net core 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the cleanest solution, but it is working for us as this is a temporary project until the consumer can migrate to our new, permanent API.

First, annotate the class with a custom ModelBinder.

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(SchoolClassBinder))]
public class SchoolClass
{}
```

Then define the custom binder.

```
    public class SchoolClassBinder: IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var model = new SchoolClass
            {
                Name = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("schoolClass[name]").ToString(),
                Level = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("schoolClass[level]").ToString()
            };            

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Still wish I knew what this syntax would be called and why it worked in the old .net framework API.